# POST request with ASP.NET Core MVC and DataDTO returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement a `POST` request in my `HomeController`. This is is the code for the POST request method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Tutoring AddTutoring(TutoringDTO tutoringToAdd)
{
        Console.WriteLine("FilteredStudents");

        Tutoring tutoring = new Tutoring
        {
            StudentId = tutoringToAdd.StudentId, //with 1 f.e. working
            Schulstufe = tutoringToAdd.Schulstufe, //with 2 f.e. working
            SubjectId = tutoringToAdd.SubjectId, //with 3 f.e. working
        };

        db.Tutorings.Add(tutoring);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return tutoring;
}
```

If I replace the `StudentId`, `Schulstufe` and `SubjectId` with constant values, it works.

This is the `TutoringDTO`:

```
public class TutoringDTO
{
    public int Schulstufe { get; set; }
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public int? SubjectId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the `Tutorings` class in my DbLib:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace AjaxTutoringsDb
{
    public partial class Tutoring
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Schulstufe { get; set; }
        public int? StudentId { get; set; }
        public int? SubjectId { get; set; }

        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the request body in Postman:

```
{ "studentId": "6", "subjectId": "1", "schulstufe": "1" }
```

And this is the response body of Postman:

```
{
    "id": 136,
    "schulstufe": 0,
    "studentId": null,
    "subjectId": null,
    "student": null, //this doesn't matter
    "subject": null  //this doesn't matter
}
```

To sum up everything, the problem is that if I send dynamic values to the server I always get null in the response body and the data I send to the server isn't  correctly stored.

Comment: @Crowcoder now I get an exception when sending this {"studentId": 6,"subjectId": 1, "schulstufe": 1}

Comment: Is you code on the client or server.  There is a controller on both client and server.  He is what happens 1) Client send a Request to server (Post) 2) Sever receives Request (GET) and deserializes the body using a controller 3) Server send a query to database using deserialized data 4) Server receives the query results  from database 5) Server creates a Response (Post) with query results 6) Client receives response (Get) and deserializes the body using a controller.

Comment: @masterYoda, you need to follow jdweng's guide in form of a question (1)are you sending the data aright? (2)is the server receiving the data as i want (3) is the data being save to the db how i want (4) are you receiving the correct response from the db (5) is the resp create as you want (6) is the client receiving the response. You need to tell us at what point (what number) things stopped going as you want

Comment: Try using "Tutoring" directly instead of the dto.
Since you say when u replace with constant, it works, the error must have happened b4 that place. 
you didnt even show us what you did on postman. cos you will need to pass as body and connfirm that conntent-type is 'application/json'

Comment: @DamilolaAdegunwa Well, I replaced it with Tutoring and I used content-type 'application/json'

Comment: @masterYoda is it working now? else, is the data reaching the code?